# Loop through a MySQLi result set based on a value of a field in the set?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

In PHP, say I have a mysqli_query result set of a number of rows and columns. Like so:

```
supervisor | employee Name | + other columns of data . . . 
bob        | joe jones
bob        | roy ryan
alice      | mary doe
alice      | dan norris
alice      | diane wood
etc.. for many rows
```

What I want to do is loop through based on the field called supervisor. So that I process all the bob records, then process all the alice records, etc.

**How can I get a list of all the unique values of a column in a mysqli result set (and store them in an array) without looping through the entire dataset?**

I could probably keep a variable of the column's value and then check for changes each iteration of mysqli_fetch_assoc/array() and check if the value of the variable has changed but it seems like there is a better way to do that.

Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Can you show us what the end result should look like? Also, show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: if you want to get the number of unique fields first.. why not just do a simple query select * from supervisor group by name... Although I think this would be a waste of time.. you should be able to get ALL data from the single query then process through it in an efficient way... if you need to split data by supervisor for example... why not order by supervisor name... then when iterating through, store cur_supervisor... then check if cur_supervisor == $result['supervisor_name']... i'm making a ton of assumptions here on the limited info

Comment: Ha, yep, and we both deleted them when we saw each other's. Post yours again and I'll upvote.

Comment: @IanDrake yes I think that is it. I did not know about the function array_column. Make that into an answer and I will mark it correct.

Comment: @IanDrake - You take this one... you were first, after all :-)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson My internet connection might be 1ms faster than yours :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other comments/answers have made good points about doing this in SQL, however, if you're looking for a PHP solution you can always do the following:

`$unique_supervisors = array_unique(array_column($result_set, 'supervisor'));`

(Note: The `array_column()` function was added in version 5.5, so if you're using an ancient version of PHP, your best bet is SQL or just looping over the array.)

P.S. equal credit goes to Magnus Eriksson for posting the exact same solution at the exact same time.

Comment: Thank you both. I was unaware that the function existed so I'm glad I asked. I'm on PHP7 so it should be okay to use. 
I wonder why my question was marked down though by someone. I thought it was relatively clear and concise.

Comment: @S.Mason My guess would be that it's because the question doesn't contain any attempt to solve the issue. In general, when posting questions on SO, you need to have done extensive research and made attempts to solve the issue yourself first. Then you should add your attempts to the question so everyone knows that you've actually tried something and what you've already tried.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily get the distinct supervisor values with SQL however if you need to get data for each supervisor then you are having to perform n+1 queries and this is usually not ideal.

The better approach is to get all the data you will need in one query and then process it with PHP.